# How would I return to the start of a while statement instead of just straight breaking

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

When I try to use a break statement to go back to the start of the infinite loop, it breaks right back to the first while loop asking for pie_type. [Shown Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc8iI.png).

Comment: Please do not use images to post codes, copy the code and put it in the question as text.

Comment: [Please do not post images of your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question.

Answer (score 0):

`break` is useful to exit loop (as if in haste) due to some external condition being met.

`continue` is used to transfer control back to the beginning of loop